# User account email verification links not working

Tags: node.js, parse-server, mailgun, email-verification

I am having a lot of troubles getting verification emails to work, when a user signs up with `parse-server` (using `MailGun` & `Heroku`).

The verification link sent to the user has this form:

```
  https://myapp.herokuapp.com/apps/.............
```

but it does not work/

I get this, when clicking it:

```
  Cannot GET /apps/.......
```

And even if I type only this in the web browser:

```
  https://myapp.herokuapp.com/apps/
```

I still get this:

```
  Cannot GET /apps/
```

At one point I was suspecting I could have made some confusion between `parse-server-mailgun` and `parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter` (I am in fact not fully aware of the difference between the two), so I tried both but I still got the same kind of error.

Since, I can reach the point where a user account is actually created and a verification email is sent, I suppose I must have only made some detail mistake in my settings; but I can't see where. Any help or relevant hint from some experienced person would be highly apreciated.

In case someone think I should share some code because the explanation above is not enough, please tell me what you need to know to clarifly my point. And I will provide the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

You should see your publicServerURL to https://myapp.heroku.com/parse

Comment: If I set publicServerURL to '...myapp.herokuapp.com/parse' The error is: {"error":"unauthorized"} And if I set publicServerURL to '...myapp.herokuapp.com' The error is: Cannot GET /apps/....

Comment: There is a step by step description of how to reproduce my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49380780/parse-server-email-verification-bug.